# header text not changing c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, dropdown

I am getting data from SQL which has header_text : Last_Term and Current_Term
I need those header_text to change to the selected dropdown value.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ENRDropDownList" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ENRDropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                                runat="Server">
                                 <asp:ListItem Text="Fall 2016" Value="20172" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fall 2015" Value="20162" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fall 2014" Value="20152" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fall 2013" Value="20142" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fall 2012" Value="20132" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fall 2011" Value="20122" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fall 2010" Value="20112" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Fall 2009" Value="20102" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Suppose if we select Fall 2016, Current_Term should change to Fall 2016 and Last_Term should change to Fall 2015 (Dynamically).

So far, i ve written this logic that current and last term to change accordingly.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //List<something> clist = new List<something>();s
        //clist.Add(new something { cyear = 2016 , pyear = 2015});
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            if (Session["term"] != null)
            {
                ENRDropDownList.SelectedValue = Session["term"].ToString();
            }

            caption.Text = "Comparison of Fall Enrollment Numbers - " + ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem;
            //MyGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = clist.Find(new something { cyear = 2015 });
            MyGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView2.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView3.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView4.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView5.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView6.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView7.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView8.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView9.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView10.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
            MyGridView11.Columns[2].HeaderText = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;

        }
    }


    //string drop = Nameofthedropdownlist.Value;
    // datatable.Coloumn["Current_Term"].ColoumnName= drop;


    protected void ENRDropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        caption.Text = "Comparison of Fall Enrollment Numbers  - " + ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem;
        Session["term"] = ENRDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        MyGridView1.DataBind();
        MyGridView2.DataBind();
        MyGridView3.DataBind();
        MyGridView4.DataBind();
        MyGridView5.DataBind();
        MyGridView6.DataBind();
        MyGridView7.DataBind();
        MyGridView8.DataBind();
        MyGridView9.DataBind();
        MyGridView10.DataBind();
        MyGridView11.DataBind();

        string dropValue = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
        string drop = ENRDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value.Remove(4,1);
        int previousvalue = Convert.ToInt32(drop) - 2;


        MyGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView2.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView3.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView4.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView5.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView6.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView7.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView8.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView9.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView10.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView11.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        //MyGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = dropValue;
       // MyGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
        MyGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView2.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView3.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView4.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView5.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView6.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView7.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView8.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView9.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView10.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;
        MyGridView11.Columns[2].HeaderText = dropValue;

        //string last_Year_Value = ENRDropDownList.SelectedValue

        //Console.WriteLine(dropValue);


    }
```

When i run the code, page is loaded where, only Current_Term has changed to the selected year, but last_Term is not changed.

[Last_term not changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaWMB.png)

But, When i select another year, then Last_Term is changing.
How do i fix this, so that when page is loaded, last_term should appear.

[after i select another year last_term is changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlU0I.png)

Comment: You need to either call the ddl change event from page load (I wouldnt suggest that) or create a function you call in both places that fills everything.  So instead of haveing all the grid properties done in two sections jsut do it in one.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Fall " + Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
```

Replace it with **HeaderRow.Cells[index of cell to be changed].Text**

```
MyGridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text =ddl1.SelectedItem.Value;
```

It will surely change the Column Header of Grid.